# How to not repeat code in calculation functions?

Tags: c++

I have made a simple program that performs basic arithmetic operations on all the elements of a given array. But the problem is that the code is very repetitive and it's not a good practice to write repeated code and I can't come up with a solution to this problem.
How can we minimize code repetition in this program?

```cpp
int add(int numcount, int numarr[]){
    int total = numarr[0];

    // add all the numbers in a array
    for (int i = 1; i < numcount; i++){
        total += numarr[i];
    }

    return total;
}

int sub(int numcount, int numarr[]) {
    int total = numarr[0];

    // subtract all the numbers in array
    for (int i = 1; i < numcount; i++){
        total -= numarr[i];
    }

    return total;
}

int mul(int numcount, int numarr[]) {
    int total = numarr[0];

    // multiply all the numbers in array
    for (int i = 1; i < numcount; i++){
        total *= numarr[i];
    }

    return total;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    const int n = 5;
    int arr[n] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    
    cout << "Addition: " << add(n, arr) << endl;
    cout << "Subtraction: " << sub(n, arr) << endl;
    cout << "Multiplication: " << mul(n, arr) << endl;
}
```

Comment: `int n = 5; int arr[n] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` -- This is not valid C++.  This should be `const int n = 5;`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -- or `int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };`.

Comment: Writing repetitive code that does different things isn't necessarily bad. It's when you find yourself copy-and-paste-ing code whose sole purpose is to do **the same thing** that you need to look more carefully. The code as written is clear and straightforward. I wouldn't change it.

Comment: @PeteBecker -- Yeah, but it's that one rinky-dink character difference (`*`, `-`, etc) that is kind of bothering.

Comment: *How can we minimize code repetition in this program?* -- You can minimize the number of lines of code for each function, but you will still have the same number of different functions (`add`, `sub`, etc).  If you mean minimize the number of lines, then one single line to `std::accumulate` is all that's really necessary for those functions.

Comment: Incidentally, it seems a bit odd that `sub` begins with the first value and subtracts all of the subsequent values. There's an asymmetry there that bothers me. That may well be what's intended, but my inclination would be to have `sub` return `-add(numcount, number)`.

Answer (score 2):

> How can we minimize code repetition in this program?

Generically, by identifying the repeated structure and seeing whether we can either abstract it out, or find an existing name for it.

1. The repeated structure is just setting the running result to the first element of a container, and using a binary function to combine it with each subsequent element in turn.
2. Take a look at the [Standard Algorithms library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) and see if any existing function looks similar
3. [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) can do what we need, without any extra arguments for the `add`, and with just the appropriate [operator function object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional) for the others

So, you can trivially write

```
int add(int numcount, int numarr[]){
    return std::accumulate(numarr, numarr+numcount, 0);
}

// OK, your sub isn't actually trivial
int sub(int numcount, int numarr[]){
    return std::accumulate(numarr+1, numarr+numcount, numarr[0],
                           std::minus<int>{});
}

// could also be this - honestly it's a little hairy
// and making it behave well with an empty array
// requires an extra check. Yuck.
int sub2(int numcount, int numarr[]){
    return numarr[0] - add(numcount-1, numarr+1);
}
```

etc.

It would be slightly nicer to switch to using `std::array`, or to use ranges if you're allowed C++20 (to abstract iterator pairs over all containers).

If you must use C arrays (and they're not decaying to a pointer on their way through another function), you could write

```
template <std::size_t N>
int add(int (&numarr)[N]){
    return std::accumulate(numarr, numarr+N, 0);
}
```

to save a bit of boilerplate (passing `numcount` everywhere is just an opportunity to get it wrong).

---

NB. as mentioned in the linked docs, `std::accumulate` is an implementation of a [left fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)). So, if the standard library didn't provide accumulate, there's still an existing description of the "thing" (the particular "higher-order function") we're abstracting out of the original code, and you could write your own `foldl` template function taking the same `std::plus`, `std::minus` etc. operator functors.

Comment: note that OPs sub is `arr[0] - arr[1] - arr[2] ...` yours is the result of `add` times `-1`

Comment: Good spot! Fix incoming

Comment: end is still `numarr+numcount` not `-1`. Was about to edit but it was interleaved with your edit

Comment: Cheers, I knew I should have just switched it to iterator style

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
 auto adder = [](auto accu,auto elem) { return accu + elem; };
 auto multiplier = [](auto accu, auto elem) { return accu * elem; };


 auto sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(arr),std::end(arr),0,adder);
 auto prod = std::accumulate(std::begin(arr),std::end(arr),0,multiplier);
```

The result of `sub` is just `2*arr[0] - sum`.

Be careful with the inital value for `std::accumulate`. It determines the return type and multiplying lots of `int` can easily overflow, perhaps use `0LL` rather than `0`.

---

In cases where `std::accumulate` nor any other standard algorithm fits, and you find yourself writing very similar functions that only differ by one particular operation, you can refactor to pass a functor to one function that lets the caller specifiy what operation to apply:

```
template <typename F>
void foo(F f) {
    std::cout << f(42);
}
int identity(int x) { return x;}

int main() {
    foo([](int x) { return x;});
    foo(identity);    
}
```

Here `foo` prints to the console the result of calling some callable with parameter `42`. `main` calls it once with a lambda expression and once with a free function.

Answer (score -1):

> How can we minimize code repetition in this program?

One way to do this is to have a parameter of type `char` representing the operation that needs to be done as shown below:

```
//second parameter denotes the operator which can be +, - or *
int calc(int numcount, char oper, int numarr[])
{
    //do check here that we don't go out of bounds 
    assert(numcount > 0);
    
    int total = numarr[0]; 

    // do the operatations for all the numbers in the array
    for (int i = 1; i < numcount; i++){
        total = (oper == '-') * (total - numarr[i]) + 
                (oper == '+') * (total + numarr[i]) + 
                (oper == '*') * (total * numarr[i]); 
                 
    }
    return total;
           
}
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    std::cout << calc(6, '+', arr) << std::endl; //prints 21 
    std::cout << calc(6, '-', arr) << std::endl; //prints -19
    std::cout << calc(6, '*', arr) << std::endl; //prints 720
  
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ypI3LNksk)

Comment: Even thouth this works, this is one of the worst ways I can think of to implement this properly. Part of the reason is that you simply won't get a compiler error, if you input something other than one of the chars this is able to work with, It's probably easy to detect that `calc(6, '$', arr)` doesn't make much sense, but what about `calc(6, '/', arr)` or `calc(6, '&', arr)`? Furthermore you wouldn't be able to extend the implementation to work for `calc(6, '/', arr)`, since this could break all the other operations, since for certain arrays you'd be unnecessarily adding a divison by 0...